# How can I publish a solution to sitecore (using TDS) across the DMZ?

Tags: c#, sitecore, tds

We use Sitecore with TDS (Team Development for Sitecore) to build our website and I'm trying to set up a CI/CD build that will deploy the code to UAT servers in our DMZ, but I'm having trouble accessing the machine in the DMZ. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? How about machines not in the DMZ? (Our CM machines are inside the DMZ and our CD servers are in the DMZ). If I could get the deployment of the sitecore items to the machine in the LAN and the code to both servers I'd be good.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up some port forwarding rules on the router Ben. DMZ and non DMZ is irrelevant. What is relevant is access to the ports you need. You might look at setting up VPNs if you have multiple machines in the same zone using the  same ports. Cheers. Keith

Comment: DMZ non DMZ'ish, you need to know some credentials to connect to those instances, so you can publish your code there. With or without vpn you should be able to access those instaces. I have a feeling you are working with CenturyLink instances, they prohibit this openings, only way to publish code on DMZ is via portals, so good luck with that :(

Answer (score 0):

If continuous delivery is your goal you may want to consider something like Sitecore Ship. This allows you to install packages via http.

So rather than jumping through hoops with security and file shares/VPNs you could install TDS generated packages over http.

https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship

Answer (score 0):

For TDS to push files using its native mechanism, you will need network access to a UNC file share on the target machine. When operating across network zones, this means you need to ensure the firewall configurations allow you to perform these actions.

An easy way to test this quickly is to create a quick Robocopy call and try to copy a file across the network. Work with your internal networking team to open up the necessary ports and file permissions to write to the target. Once the robocopy works, you should be able to do more with TDS.